# Ansible archive file for few path earlier

Tags: ansible

Below is the folder structure

```
playbook
  |-groups_Vars
  |-host
  |-roles
    |-archive-artifact
      |-task
        |-main.yml
  |-archive-playbook.yml
myfile
```

In my *main.yml*, I need to archive the playbook in *playbook.tar.gz*.

```yaml
- archive:
    path: "<earlier path>/playbook/*"
    dest: "<earlier path>/playbook.tar.gz"
    format: gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder that holds a playbooks is accessible in the [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `playbook_dir`.
Getting the parent directory of a file or directory in Ansible is possible via the filter [`dirname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names).

And, [as pointed in the documentation, `path`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html#parameter-path) can be either a single element or a list of elements, so you could also have *myfile* included in that list.

So, to archive the playbook directory in the parent folder of the playbook directory, one could do:

```yaml
- archive:
    path: 
      - "{{ playbook_dir }}/*"
      - "{{ playbook_dir | dirname }}/myfile"
    dest: "{{ playbook_dir | dirname }}/playbook.tar.gz"
    format: gz
```

Comment: why do we need pipe dirname but in path e didnt mention ya. also i have updated in futuree if i have myfile, can it  archive together

Comment: Because in your question, you said you want you want _/path/to/playbook_ archived under _/path/to/playbook.tar.gz_.

Comment: The _myfile_. story is not clear, do you have a folder with only a folder _playbook_ and a file _myfile_, or do you have other things that you do not want archived?

Comment: thank you for the info. i like to archive all. based on ur code i can tweak little. but it works as expected from the documentation u have sharedf